# JTabbedPane how to determine that user left tab?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I wonder, if it possible to determine, that user left certain tab. For example, we have 2 tabs: "omg" and "lol". The current tab is omg.  I want to know that user switched from "omg" to "lol"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding a change listener to the `JTabbedPane` you will know when the tab selection changes.

Updated: Added tab index tracking

```
tabbedPane.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    int lastTabIndex = -1;
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         int newIndex = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
         if (lastTabIndex == 1 && newIndex == 2) { //or whatever check/combination of checks you would like
             //switched from tab 1 to tab 2!
         }

         //or just check for leaving tab 1
         if (lastTabIndex == 1) {
             //left tab 1!
         }

         //etc

         lastTabIndex = newIndex;
    }
});
```

Comment: Or as @Hovercraft said, directly on the JTabbedPane, exactly the same thing.

Comment: exactly. I will delete my answer as it is redundant. 1+

Comment: Yeah, I know about this listener and I still do not understand how can i retrieve the tab which user LEFT, not which is selected now. I'm really sorry if it is obvious and really simple to understand, but could you, please, tell some more details?

Comment: You can save the selected tab (index for example) every time it changes, updating the example...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the source I used for this, but I'm pretty sure what I did was extend JTabbedPane and override setSelectedIndex(int).  It is called when the index is GOING to be changed to the indicated number, and I used it to validate things on the pane that was going to be left.  If your logic does not execute super.setSelectedIndex(int), then you don't leave the pane (which is what I was after).